# Can I leave out `if ( ! defined ...)` when defining plugin constants?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm writing a WordPress plugin. At the top of the plugin file, I define some constants. Can I leave out the `if ( ! defined( 'THE_CONSTANT' ) )` tests?

Some other plugins that I've studied includes such `if ( ! defined` tests, some don't. Personally, I don't know why my plugin file would ever be included twice?

The reason I don't want to include `if ( ! defined ...` is that I think this is hard to read:
(*XYZABC* would be the plugin name)

```
if ( ! defined( 'XYZABC_PLUGIN_BASENAME' ) )
    define( 'XYZABC_PLUGIN_BASENAME', plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
if ( ! defined( 'XYZABC_SETTINGS_SLUG' ) )
    define( 'XYZABC_SETTINGS_SLUG', 'xyzabc_comments_options' );
if ( ! defined( 'XYZABC_ENABLED_QUERY_PARAM' ) )
    define( 'XYZABC_ENABLED_QUERY_PARAM', 'xyzabc-comments-enabled' );
```

But this is relatively nice to read:

```
define( 'XYZABC_PLUGIN_BASENAME', plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'XYZABC_SETTINGS_SLUG', 'xyzabc_comments_options' );
define( 'XYZABC_ENABLED_QUERY_PARAM', 'xyzabc-comments-enabled' );
```

---

**Update:

Workaround.** I defined this function, and then the duplicated-constant-name issue is mostly gone.

```
function myplugin_define_default($constant_name, $value) {
    if (! defined($constant_name))
        define($constant_name, $value);
}
```

So now my code looks like so:

```
define( 'XYZABC_PLUGIN_BASENAME', plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
xyzabc_define_default( 'XYZABC_SETTINGS_SLUG', 'xyzabc_comments_options' );
xyzabc_define_default( 'XYZABC_ENABLED_QUERY_PARAM', 'xyzabc-comments-enabled' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing the `!defined()` check you allow earlier code to define that constant before you. This could be useful, for example, if a user is allowed to define its own values for some constants in a file like `wp-config.php`.

As for code readability, you may consider using the following one-liner, although you could put a regular `if` on a single line as well.

```
defined('XYZABC_PLUGIN_BASENAME') or define('XYZABC_PLUGIN_BASENAME', 'your_value');
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, didn't know that people sometimes defined *plugin* constants in `wp-config.php`. I suppose people do that, if the plugin Settings page isn't flexible enough. — Perhaps I'll keep `if ( ! defined` sometimes then — I can think of some weird cases when people might want to redefined some of the constants.

Comment: Your `defined ... or define` is more readable than the `if ( ! defined ...` version, I think.

Comment: I added a perhaps even more readable version in my original post.

Comment: Wrapping it in a function is possible. Note that even though your code may look prettier, people who are reading it will need to look up your custom function first. Not a big deal, but I’d prefer sticking to native define functions here.